# Unable to use curl PUT for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, command-line, terminal

I am new to [elastisearch](https://elastic.co) so I'm sorry if this is a newbie question.

Basically,I am trying top `PUT` some data into an index that I have created.

I am using this code(in the command prompt):

```
curl -XPUT -x "" "http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d '{"user" : "kimchy", "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12","message" : "trying"}
```

But in the command prompt, I get this error:

```
[1/3]: http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d 'user : kimchy  --> <stdout>
--_curl_--http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d 'user : kimchy
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid v
ersion format: -D 'USER : KIMCHY  HTTP/1.1"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception
","reason":"invalid version format: -D 'USER : KIMCHY  HTTP/1.1"},"status":400}
[2/3]: http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d ' post_date : 2009-11-15T14:12:12  --> <s
tdout>
--_curl_--http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d ' post_date : 2009-11-15T14:12:12
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid v
ersion format: -D ' POST_DATE : 2009-11-15T14:12:12  HTTP/1.1"}],"type":"illegal
_argument_exception","reason":"invalid version format: -D ' POST_DATE : 2009-11-
15T14:12:12  HTTP/1.1"},"status":400}
[3/3]: http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d 'message : trying  --> <stdout>
--_curl_--http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/' -d 'message : trying
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"invalid v
ersion format: -D 'MESSAGE : TRYING  HTTP/1.1"}],"type":"illegal_argument_except
ion","reason":"invalid version format: -D 'MESSAGE : TRYING  HTTP/1.1"},"status"
:400}
```

Please help.I know its so simple but I just can't find it.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

When I try:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/doc/1' -d '{"user" : "kimchy", "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12","message" : "trying"}'
```

I get(in the command prompt):

```
*/

/* Page basics */
* {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

html body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #efefef;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #1e1e1e;
}

/* Page displayed title area */
#titles {
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        background: url('http://www.squid-cache.org/Artwork/SN.png') no-repeat l
eft;
}

/* initial title */
#titles h1 {
        color: #000000;
}
#titles h2 {
        color: #000000;
}

/* special event: FTP success page titles */
#titles ftpsuccess {
        background-color:#00ff00;
        width:100%;
}

/* Page displayed body content area */
#content {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #ffffff;
}

/* General text */
p {
}

/* error brief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
        margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-ser
if; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; float: right; }
 --></style>
</head><body>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href
="http:///">http:///</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Unable to determine IP address from host name <q></q></b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>The DNS server returned:</p>
<blockquote id="data">
<pre>Invalid hostname</pre>
</blockquote>

<p>This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in t
he URL. Check if the address is correct.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%
20-%20ERR_DNS_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20asoju.unilag.edu.ng%0D%0AErrPage%3A%2
0ERR_DNS_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ADNS%20ErrMsg%3A%20Invalid%20hostname
%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Fri,%2001%20Mar%202019%2015%3A50%3A22%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClie
ntIP%3A%20196.45.55.33%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APUT%20%2F%20HTTP%2F1.0%
0AHost%3A%20%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20curl%2F7.64.0%0D%0AAccept%3A%20*%2F*%0D%0AProx
y-Connection%3A%20Keep-Alive%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%206%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20a
pplication%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:50:22 GMT by asoju.unilag.edu.ng (squid/3.1.6)<
/p>
<!-- ERR_DNS_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/st
rict.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
 /*
 Stylesheet for Squid Error pages
 Adapted from design by Free CSS Templates
 http://www.freecsstemplates.org
 Released for free under a Creative Commons Attribution 2.5 License
*/

/* Page basics */
* {
        font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}

html body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #efefef;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #1e1e1e;
}

/* Page displayed title area */
#titles {
        margin-left: 15px;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-left: 100px;
        background: url('http://www.squid-cache.org/Artwork/SN.png') no-repeat l
eft;
}

/* initial title */
#titles h1 {
        color: #000000;
}
#titles h2 {
        color: #000000;
}

/* special event: FTP success page titles */
#titles ftpsuccess {
        background-color:#00ff00;
        width:100%;
}

/* Page displayed body content area */
#content {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #ffffff;
}

/* General text */
p {
}

/* error brief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
        margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-ser
if; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; float: right; }
 --></style>
</head><body>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href
="http:///">http:///</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Unable to determine IP address from host name <q></q></b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>The DNS server returned:</p>
<blockquote id="data">
<pre>Invalid hostname</pre>
</blockquote>

<p>This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in t
he URL. Check if the address is correct.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%
20-%20ERR_DNS_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20asoju.unilag.edu.ng%0D%0AErrPage%3A%2
0ERR_DNS_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20%5Bnone%5D%0D%0ADNS%20ErrMsg%3A%20Invalid%20hostname
%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Fri,%2001%20Mar%202019%2015%3A50%3A22%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClie
ntIP%3A%20196.45.55.33%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APUT%20%2F%20HTTP%2F1.0%
0AHost%3A%20%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20curl%2F7.64.0%0D%0AAccept%3A%20*%2F*%0D%0AProx
y-Connection%3A%20Keep-Alive%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%206%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20a
pplication%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Fri, 01 Mar 2019 15:50:22 GMT by asoju.unilag.edu.ng (squid/3.1.6)<
/p>
<!-- ERR_DNS_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 7:
trying}'
      ^
```

Comment: `invalid version format: -D 'USER : KIMCHY  HTTP/1.1`. Check your quotes. URL start with `"` but ends with `'`, and never closes last quote

Comment: @Justinas I know but what does that mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing double quotes and single quotes

```
"http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/'
^                           ^
```

- you're missing a single quote at the end of your payload
- you're missing a mapping type and and id
- you're missing the Content-Type HTTP header

Try this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/doc/1' -d '{"user" : "kimchy", "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12","message" : "trying"}'
```

On Windows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/doc/1" -d "{\"user\" : \"kimchy\", \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\"message\" : \"trying\"}"
```

Comment: <p>Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.</p>

<p>Some possible problems are:</p>
<ul>
<li><p>Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be <q>http://</q> or similar
)</p></li>
<li><p>Missing hostname</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.</p></li>
</ul>

Comment: I accepted ur answer  thugh it didnt work for being kind

Comment: Hmm, I tested it on my machine and it did work... Not sure what's different on yours. Can you upload a screenshot of your terminal window?

Comment: Are you on a Windows system?

Comment: Yes Windows 7 Professional 32bit OS

Comment: Ok, the issue is that Windows doesn't support single quotes on the command line... See my updated answer that uses only double quotes (and also escapes double quotes in the payload)

Comment: Sorry could we move our discussion to chat?

Comment: Ok.Please give me a second